# How to understand what a database schema means?

Tags: database, database-design

I am trying to understand a database schema but I am finding it hard to understand why the connections are like they are.
http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/bicycle_rental/images/data_model.gif

Comment: Have you tried: http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/bicycle_rental/ and the link to "Understand the Data Model" ?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't clearly explains with this example

Comment: You'll need to update the question with exactly what it is you don't understand. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Time to read an information modeling & database design textbook. Your question just asks us to write yet another one with a bespoke tutorial. If you don't understand a particular presentation then ask a question about the first place you are stuck. PS Please use text, not links/images, for text, including tables (use block code format) & ERDs (use DDL). Quote or paraphrase if necessary with credit (use block quote format).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to understand a database schema is to connect the data back to the underlying subject matter.  The schema usually lays out the logical structure of the data, including tables, columns, and constraints.  The semantics of the data sometimes fall by the wayside.  Based on your question, that seems to be the case here.

The names of the columns make a great deal of sense to me, but I know almost nothing about the bicycle rental business.  If you could talk to someone who actually runs a bicycle rental, that person might make sense out of the data for you.  Or that expert might give you a picture that's at variance with the model.

The most important thing for making sense of the whole picture is realizing what the primary keys are,  and what foreign keys reference them.  Fortunately,  these have been flagged for you in the diagram.  The columns labelled PK are primary keys.  The columns labelled FK are foreign keys.  They don't say what they refer to, but you can infer that from the names.  For example,  Rentals.Bicycle_ID clearly references Bicycles.Bicycle_ID.

The ones labelled PF are both foreign keys and (part of) a primary key.  You see that in the Bicycles_in_Shops table.  This frequently occurs in tables that implement a many-to-many relationship, where two foreign keys, taken together, make up the primary key for the table containing the relationship.

One exercise you might put for yourself is to ask which tables represent entities and which tables represent relationships in an ER model of the subject matter.  This assumes you know what an entity is and what a relationship is.  If you don't know that, it's worth learning it,  even though ER modeling is slightly different from relational modeling.

Hope this helps.